# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 96 path

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

This is my json

```
{
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "responseA": {
        "responseB": [{
                    "response": {...},
                    "request": "\/observations\/atlanta,ga"
                }, {
                    "response": [{...}],
                    "request": "\/forecasts\/atlanta,ga"
                },
                ...
            ]
    }
}
```

I creat my class for the json from here: 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

and I find the error of the title is from the two "response" which are array and object.

As I said Ｉanalyze the that by Retrofit, How can I analy a json like this with the "repsonse" of two types(array and object) by Retrofit2.0? Thanks~*

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();`
```

This is log:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 96 path $.response.responses[0].response
      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
      at retrofit.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:36)
      at retrofit.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:24)
      at retrofit.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:148)
      at retrofit.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:116)
      at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:61)
```

Comment: please post error logcat ....

Comment: As if I change my response from object to array, it will said need an arry but got a object....

Comment: your json start with arrya

Comment: normal json start with { } barces and array json start with [ ] barces ....

Comment: Could you fix your formatting? I had a look but if I edit it, then some of your intentionally may be lost as there is some ambiguity. Thanks...

Comment: where is your Api call ??

Comment: Hi I have figured out your json response error. kindly check answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't satisfied the text format of stackoverflow, I add my json code as a picture in it. Thanks

Comment: bro please post your Api call ....

Comment: @SushilKumar The answer below is correct.

Comment: @SushilKumar Thanks for improving my json format, but the main problem is  how can I use Retrofit 2.0 to analyze the json which the "response" has two types？

Comment: bro please thanx to @RameshKumar . He improve your json format ....

Comment: in response.body() you got the Pogo class . Just use that pojo class for your data .

Comment: Oh, haha  thanks @RameshKumar for improving my json format~

Comment: @SushilKumar Yes, but how to use Retrofit to judge the two types?

Answer (score 1):

there is mistake in your json:

responseB first object has a **response object** and second object has **response array**. this is creating problem

```
{

"success":true,

"error":null,

"responseA":{

  "responseB":[  
     {  

        "response":{... ***// This is object***
              },
        "request":"\/observations\/atlanta,ga"
     },
     {  
        "response":[   ***// This is Array***
           { ...
              }
        ],
        "request":"\/forecasts\/atlanta,ga"
     },
... ]

} }
```

You have make a same structure for arrays object. 
Hope this help.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for improving my json format, but how can I use Retrofit 2.0 to analyze the json which the "response" has two types？

Comment: for this case you have to parse manually, get JsonObject from Retrofit. then parse it with check if it is json object or array..